# Nested templates and constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constructor

**Edit**:
Note that my final purpose here is not having the class working, is just learning more about templates :-)

Suppose you have a template class which implements a vector:

```
template <typename T>
class Vector
{
    public:
        Vector(size_t dim) {
            dimension = dim;
            elements = new T[dim];
        }
        /* Here more stuff, like operator[] etc... */
    private:
        size_t dimension;
        T * elements;
}
```

And suppose you want to build a matrix with it. A matrix is just a vector of vectors, thus it can be designed as follows:

```
template <typename T>
class Matrix : public Vector<Vector<T> >
{
    /*...*/
}
```

And here comes trouble: In the constructor I need to provide rows and columns as parameter to the internal vectors. It should be something like

```
template <typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix (size_t ncols, size_t nrows)
         : Vector<Vector<T> > /* Here I need to specify size for both
                               * internal and external vectors */
{
}
```

Obviously I cannot write `Vector<Vector<T>(nrows)>(ncols)`, but that's what I would need!

A possible solution would be including size inside the template:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
class Vector
{
    public:
        Vector() {
            elements = new T[N];
        }
        /* Here more stuff, like operator[] etc... */
    private:
        T * elements;
}
```

Hence I would no longer need constructor parameters, but this also forces me to write clumsy code with templates everywhere (by exmample, every function using a `Vector` should be declared as

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
void foo (Vector<T,N> &vec) {...}
```

Do you have better solutions?

**EDIT:**

As solution I took inspiration from Mr Fooz's and chubsdad's posts. That's how I fixed the problem:

```
/* The RowAccess class is just an array wrapper which raises an exception
 * if you go out of bounds */
template <typename T>
class RowAccess
{
    public:

        RowAccess (T * values, unsigned cols) : values(vals), cols(c) {}

        T & operator[] (unsigned i) throw (MatrixError) {
            if (i < cols) return values[i];
            else throw MatrixError("Column out of bound");
        }

    private:
        T * values;
        unsigned cols;
};

template <typename T>
class Matrix
{
    public:
        Matrix (unsigned rows, unsigned cols) {...}
        virtual ~Matrix () {...}

        RowAccess<T> operator[] (unsigned row) {
            if (row < rows) return RowAccess<T>(values + cols * row, cols);
            else throw MatrixError("Row out of boundary");
        }

    private:
        unsigned rows;
        unsigned cols;
        T * values;
};
```

Thanks a lot to everyone!

Comment: Why is `foo` "clumsy"? Even without the N parameter it would still be templated.

Comment: Both the `size_t N` and the runtime `dim` value solve different problems. If the size is constant and known at compile time, you *should* use the `size_t N` way, because it employs type-checking.  A possible overflow somewhere is then diagnosed at compiletime. In this case there is also no need for `new` at all - just put a normal array inside, like `boost::array<T, N>`.

Comment: @jon hanson: yes, but types are far more general than values, thus defining `foo(Vector<int> &vec);` it's better than `foo(Vector<int,5> &vec);`. For the second one I would prefer to define foo as template function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't what you asked, but there's a good chance the matrix would be better of implemented as a single linear vector where you provide high-level access methods that do the indexing (e.g. elmLoc=row*ncols+col).  This way you don't need to create and initialize a vector of vectors.  You also don't need to worry about accidentally having some inner vectors of the differing size.  All dense matrix implementations I have ever used use a single linear vector as the underlying implementation.

Answer (score 3):

In OO terms, I would vote for "has" a relationship between Matrix and a Vector. A Matrix has vectors, rather than a Matrix "is a" vector, which means that Matrix should not derive from Vector.

EDIT 1: A small correction. "..which means that Matrix should not derive "publicly" from Vector". Private inheritance may be still fine.

Comment: This is indeed a good idea (simple is good!), but requires me to redefine twice similar methods (like the operator[] one)

Comment: @Dacav: Inheritance and composition are NOT the same thing, and inheritance is NOT for code re-use. You open yourself up to undefined behaviour by allowing an implicit cast to vector<vector<T>>, as it does not have a virtual destructor. When you have to define your own operator[] for the Matrix class, it is a one-liner to forward it to the underlying vector.

Comment: @DeadMG: Well, this is a wise point of view (+1 at your comment). However I'm trying to learn how to deal with this kind of situation (namely the one I described in my question) which happens with inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

Use placement-new like this (burried behind the `uninitialized_fill` call)

```
template <typename T>
class Vector
{
    public:
        Vector(size_t dim, T const& c = T()) {
            dimension = dim;
            elements =
              static_cast<T*>(operator new(sizeof(T) * dim));
            std::uninitialized_fill(elements, elements + dim, c);
        }
        /* Here more stuff, like operator[] etc... */
    private:
        size_t dimension;
        T * elements;
};
```

Then you can call the constructor with `Matrix::Vector(ncols, Vector<T>(nrows))` (you don't need to repeat the argument for the outer Vector, because `Vector` refers to `Vector< Vector<T> >` automatically since you inherit from the outer Vector. You need to make sure to call destructors manually before doing `operator delete(elements)` in the destructor then.

You might also want to embed the vector as a member, which i would probably prefer because I imagine not necessarily all operations of the outer vector make sense for a matrix. Then the initialization looks like `m(ncols, Vector<T>(nrows))`.

---

It should be noted that `std::vector` can also be used for this

```
template <typename T>
class Vector
{
    public:
        Vector(size_t dim, T const& c = T()):elements(dim, c)
        { }
    private:
        std::vector<T> elements;
};
```

This is an easy and safe way to accomplish that, and you get automatic memory management.

Comment: Basically you are using `operator new(sizeof(T) * dim)` instead of `new T[dim]` in order to avoid the constructor to be called?

Comment: ...Also is it legal to call the super constructor as `Matrix::Vector(...)`?

Comment: @Dacav you need to call it that way. If you just say `Vector(...)` then the name will not be looked up in the base-class, because it depends on a template parameter. It's completely legal to name the base-class type in any way you see fit. You don't need `typename` here, because like with base-clause class-names, it's implied that you are naming a type.

Comment: @Johannes: Sorry to ask here but did you see what happened to [Neil Butterworth's](http://stackoverflow.com/users/69307/nb69307) account?

Comment: @Prasoon wait, WTF. How did he lose all his points? What happened to the guy.

Comment: @Johannes : I have asked the related question [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61077/why-does-neil-butterworth-say-please-delete-me). :-)

Comment: @Johannes Schaub: I appreciate your answer for the wizardry (+1), but I think that asking the user to avoid the constructor is weird and counter intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you expect from your Vector (and  Matrix) class.

Either you want the size to be determined at runtime, and in that case, I'd suggest adding a `resize()` function which would allow you to size the Vector in the constructor as you like.

```
template <typename T>
class Vector
{
    public:
        Vector(size_t dim) {
            dimension = dim;
            elements = new T[dim];
        }
        Vector() : dimension(0), elements(0) {} // you need default constructor
        void resize(size_t dim) { // note: this could be implemented a lot better
          T* new_elements=new T[dim];
          for(int i=0; i<dim && i<dimension; i++)
            new_elements[i]=elements[i];
          delete [] elements;
          elements=new_elements; dimension=dim;
        }
        /* Here more stuff, like operator[] etc... */
    private:
        size_t dimension;
        T * elements;
}
```

You would then resize your `Vectors` in the `Matrix` constructor in a loop.

If you want the size of your vector or matrix to be determined at compile time, the best thing probably would be to use the template non-type argument as you suggested.

Comment: This may be a good solution. I also tought about it. The problem is that it allows the user to create an empty vector/matrix, thus makes the library weaker and more error-prone.